# Does every North Korean home have a radio that can't be turned off?

Tags: law, north-korea

[VillageOfJoy](http://villageofjoy.com/north-korea-most-isolated-country-in-the-world/) claims that:

> 14 Interesting Facts about North Korea
>
> 1. You can’t turn off the government radio installed in your home, only reduce the volume. [...]

There are many of web-sites with similar claims: [1](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/North_Korea),
[2](http://radicalsahm.blogspot.com.au/2010/06/radio-they-cant-turn-off-is-clincher.html).

[This photo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mytripsmypics/6283245121/in/photostream/) by  photographer [Eric Lafforgue](http://www.ericlafforgue.com/) purports to be an example of such a radio.

Is this true now? Did it used to be true? What sort of messages are/were sent over these radios?

I am not sure if it is technically a radio or rather a speaker. Most areas are not connected to the electricity grid. And I could not find telegraph poles on aereal pictueres yet, so it is interesting how this things work. Perhaps a fixed frequency radio on batteries is included.

**Edit:** I found this BBC video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRuqustZzKM at 1:43 min one can hear the speaker. It seems to be installed in flats in the cities.

Comment: This may be tricky to answer definitively. North Korean laws are unlikely to be easily available on the web. I look forward to seeing how people tackle this one.

Comment: The website that you cite don't make the claim that every home has a radio. RationalWiki points to people in town and cities (as opposed to villages) having such radio's.

Comment: seems to come straight out of 1984...

Comment: A more interesting claim might be the existence of a radio that is unaffected by having its power supply cut.  that would be radical.

Comment: @matt_black - the only thing I can think of that satisfies that requirement is a crystal radio ... And those are trivial to make/break. Factoring-in NK's apparent power problems, though, an it seems highly improbable that such a device could be in every home and never turn off

Comment: I've never heard of a crystal radio with enough power to make a loud-speaker audible, only earphones, and then still at a very volume.

Comment: I feel this image should be enough to debunk this claim: https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2014/02/25/08/v4-North-Korea-at-night.jpg

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> **Does every North Korean home have a radio ...**

No,

[image: Bar graph showing access to media in N Korea]

[North Koreans in a changing media environment](http://audiencescapes.org/sites/default/files/A_Quiet_Opening_FINAL_InterMedia.pdf)

[image: N Korean farm]
<sup>Photo by AP photographer David Guttenfelder</sup>

> A communal farm compound near Kaesong  ...
>   Ordinary North Koreans rarely have access to electricity

[Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2022821/Inside-lost-world-North-Korea-Incredible-pictures-life-planets-secretive-nation.html#ixzz2GA5ZuVDQ)

Of course, this doesn't rule out battery-powered radios, but it does support the notion that some N Korean homes might be too poor to own their own radio.

---

> **... that can't be turned off?**

A commenter to the linked photo

[image: Radio]
*<sup>photo by [Eric Lafforgue](http://www.ericlafforgue.com/)</sup>*
says

> well, In South Korea, those kind of speakers in apartment home only use for public announcement of apartment managing office. but in north korea, government took control to whole apartment....

So, to speculate a little: the pictured N korean home "radio" is probably also not a radio receiver but a loudspeaker for a communal system for relaying announcements. To be of value in emergencies, such loudspeaker units would probably not be equipped with an off-switch.

---

**... that can't be retuned?**

As pointed out by Oddthinking in a comment below:

> All radio frequencies are fixed to the official broadcasting service channels and sealed. If the seal is found broken, the person involved is assumed to be guilty of listening to South Korean or other foreign broadcasting services and is treated as a political prisoner."

From [Korea Institute for National Unification's White Paper on Human Rights in North Korea **2012**](http://www.kinu.or.kr/eng/pub/pub_04_01.jsp)

It is possible that a reporter has accidentally transformed "can't retune" to "can't turn off".

This might not apply to whatever report included the photo of a wall-mounted "radio" that lacks any obvious off-switch.

Comment: What if they use batteries? You need to cite that the answer is no - not deduce it from something else.

Comment: @Skliwz: answer updated to avoid the thorny problem of providing evidence that battery powered radios can have the batteries removed.

Comment: Fascinating reading! Via the references, I found the [Korea Institute for National Unification's White Paper on Human Rights in North Korea 2012](http://www.kinu.or.kr/eng/pub/pub_04_01.jsp): "All radio frequencies are fixed to the official broadcasting
service channels and sealed. If the seal is found broken, the person involved is assumed to be guilty of listening to South Korean or other foreign broadcasting services and is treated as a political prisoner." (It explains this law is circumvented.) I speculate this has been transmogrified from "can't re-tune" to "can't turn off".

Comment: Your link `North Koreans in a changing media environment` was very interesting. Although the number of 250 asked people are not many for a statistic.

Comment: To be honest, I'm going to go out on a limb and guess this is a '''yes''' but with something lost in translation. China had "Red Loudspeakers" in houses (you can see one at the [Yin Yu Tang house](http://www.pem.org/visi/yin_yu_tang) at the Pedbody Essex Museum which were in all of the homes and wired to village PA system. Not quite radio per se, but I can see how it could be lost in translation.

Comment: Really? We are using Daily Mail as references now?

Comment: @Sam: I take your point but the FAQ and the Welcome say "references" without qualification: Some may prefer **[Time](http://www.time.com/time/world/article/0,8599,366219,00.html)** - *"A Korea-American businessman who visited the city of Kaesong recently was shocked to learn it had had no electricity for 10 days"*  ... *"smaller cities lack regular electricity"* or **[New Scientist](http://www.newscientist.com/blogs/shortsharpscience/2011/12/satellite-image-shows-kim-jong.html)** - *"The capital Pyongyang, near the western coast, is one of the only places in the country with electricity."*

Comment: I grew up in USSR and was fascinated by electronics; we had a "radio" in our flat which, upopn disassembly, proved to be nothing more than a speaker, a variable resistor, and a two-pronged plug for connecting it to the signal. My grandma had a similar radio but this one was hard-wired and not un-pluggable (but the resistor had an "off" position). My friends report similar system all across Russia; lots of people still have them installed. So no, these devices do not require batteries, but I do realise I'm only providing anecdotal evidence here...

Comment: I think that it's worth editing @Oddthinking's comment into the answer, as I think it *is* the answer...

Comment: People are splitting hairs over batteries and electricity. The bigger question is, do they make people listen to propaganda? I suspect yes.

Comment: @romkyns We had the same system back in 1980s - power and signal were provided from a retransmitting device/amp in the apartment building basements. According to local electronic experts, it also had the nice property that with appropriate gear, they can be used as listening devices - electromechanically, any directly connected speaker cone obviously also functions as a microphone, and you can substract the "expected" signal from precision measurements of that wire to hear what is happening in the apartment.

Answer (score 0):

It was stated this was the case in a BBC Documentary in North Korea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSrcLC6Zz54&feature=youtu.be&t=1m46s

This is by no means the answer: There may well, however been a translation error that they do not want to turn it off, instead of being unable to. Perhaps even it is only the case with certain (new?) homes in Pyongyang. Indeed in the documentary the journalist says "every kitchen in the block" rather than "everyone kitchen in North Korea".

It obviously seems unrealistic that such signals could be broadcast throughout North Korea, let alone have the electricity to power these radios.

It is also worth mentioning that North Korean radios are sealed once brought; if the seal is broken you are deemed a political prisoner for trying to listen to South Korea radio. This is apparently checked by random spot checks. This could be used to enforce the rules against turning fitted radios off?

Whilst it wouldn't be practical for all houses to have this propaganda distribution mechanism, a lot certainly could. I am still very sceptical that this is one thing that has literally been taken from Nineteen Eighty Four and attributed to North Korea, maybe in order for a journalist to make the sinister nature of it more obvious.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) The only reference you provide is to the documentary that the original poster saw. We are looking for higher quality confirmation. The rest of your claims need references too.